# SMO - How to script an object in a Dynamic SQL style? (IF NOT EXISTS)

Tags: sql-server, smo

When I use SMO to script a procedure with the IncludeIfNotExists set to true, it first creates the procedure and then alters it. Is there a way for it to just create the procedure in a dynamic SQL style? (like in SSMS)

This is what I get from the SMO:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[proc_a]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_a] AS' 
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_a] 
AS
BEGIN 
-- etc..
END
GO
```

I want something like this instead:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[proc_a]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_a] 
AS
BEGIN
-- etc..

END
' 
END
GO
```

Comment: So if the proc already exists and has a different definition than the one scripted, you want to leave the old definition in place instead of changing it to match the scripted definition? I'm curious as to your use case.

Comment: My use case is that I want to create two different versions of the same procedure depending on a parameter so I'm going to replace the IF CONDITION with a different condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody interested, using the SQL 2008 SMO assembly generates the code with Dynamic-SQL Style while using SQL 2017 generates the code with the ALTER statement.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
```

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
```